# Undefined symbol _zgemm_ when I link armadillo to clblas

Tags: armadillo

Can I link armadillo to clBLAS to use an AMD GPU on macOS?

I've been using armadillo for over a year, linked to libnvblas using an NVidia GPU with no problems via the CUDA library.  But nvidia cards are getting harder to get on macos, so I just got a Radeon RX 580. I'm trying to use it via clBLAS.  I've tried both a macports clBLAS installation, and building it from source. When I build from source all the clBLAS tests run successfully.

But when I compile simple armadillo code using

```
g++-mp-6 speedtest.cpp -o speedtest_gpu -O2 -I ../include -DARMA_DONT_USE_WRAPPER -L/opt/local/lib -lclblas -llapack
```

I get

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_zgemm_", referenced from:
      void arma::glue_times_redirect2_helper<false>::apply<arma::Mat<std::complex<double> >, arma::Mat<std::complex<double> > >(arma::Mat<arma::Mat<std::complex<double> >::elem_type>&, arma::Glue<arma::Mat<std::complex<double> >, arma::Mat<std::complex<double> >, arma::glue_times> const&) in cc5i4IPr.o
      _main in cc5i4IPr.o
```

and a similar error for`_zgemv_`.  When I look in `libclBLAS.dylib` I don't see`_zgemm_` like I do in libnvblas or libblis, both of which compile successfully.

Compiling with

```
g++-mp-6 speedtest.cpp -o speedtest_gpu -O2 -I ../include -DARMA_DONT_USE_WRAPPER -L/opt/local/lib -lclblas -lblas -llapack
```

works but then it runs on the CPUs, not the GPUs.

(when I had the nvidia card

```
g++-mp-6 speedtest.cpp -o speedtest_gpu -O2 -I ../include -DARMA_DONT_USE_WRAPPER -L/Developer/NVIDIA/CUDA-9.2/lib -lnvblas -lblas -llapack
```

worked fine and ran on the nvidia GPU.)

Answer (score 0):

The answer is: No: clblas does not provide an API compatible with blas.  However CLBlast (https://github.com/CNugteren/CLBlast) does provide an API that is very close to blas, and it is not difficult to write wrappers that provide the same functionality as nvidia's nvblas and works on AMD GPUs.